# Proof of expectation of mean of normal distribution is 0

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

[image]

I am reading a book in which the proof of Expectation of normal is 0 is proved. I couldn't figure out how the right hand integral of equation 6.1.2 is less than infinity and how c1 is exactly chosen?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Where is this from ? It is in fact **not true** that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-c_1 x} <\infty$$
You'd need to replace $x$ by $|x|$ for it to be true.

Comment: Can you explain your statement

Comment: If $c_1>0$, then $e^{-c_1 x}\to \infty$ as $x\to-\infty$, so the integral $\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-c_1 x} dx$ is trivially divergent.

Comment: I found a pdf version of this textbook in which (6.1.2) is correctly rendered: in particular, it shows that "$e^{-c_1 x}$" is intended to be "$e^{-c_1|x|}$" (a function of the *absolute value* of $x$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one (pdf) copy of this passage the assertion instead is

> There exists $c_1\gt 0$ such that $f(x) = \max\{|x|,x^2\}e^{-x^2/2}\le c_1 e^{-c_1 |x|}$ for all $x\in \mathbb R.$

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

In this version, "$-c_1 x$" is "$-c_1|x|.$"  Nevertheless, **the assertion is false.**

*A good way to study arguments like this is to plot the functions involved.*  Here are the graphs of $|x|e^{-x^2/2}$ (dotted orange),  $x^2 e^{-x^2/2}$ (dashed green), and their maximum (solid blue).

[image]

What the text *intends* to do is bound the first two curves above by a curve whose area is easy to find and is finite.  *That cannot be done using curves of the form $c \exp(-c |x|).$*  The best any curve of this form can do at the points where $f$ is maximized is shown in orange here:

[image]

It's not even close to covering the graph of $f.$

**The problem is easily fixed** by considering an even simpler comparison curve, such as $c \exp(-|x|)$ for some value of $c$ to be found.  A little Calculus will show that $c=4$ (barely) works and any larger value of $c$ therefore works with room to spare:

[image]

The area under the dashed orange (bi-exponential) curve is $8.$  Consequently, the areas under the graphs of $|x| \exp(-x^2/2)$ and $x^2\exp(-x^2/2)$ must each be less than $8.$  Because $8$ is finite, the point is made.